# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, substr

The problem is, I have worked on the script jquery.min.js version 1.4. After had to upgrade to version 1.9.1, and there was a problem.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'substr' of undefined.
```

Tell me what to do. 
This part of the code in which the error occurred.

```
var processCaption = function(settings){
                var nivoCaption = $('.nivo-caption', slider);
                if(vars.currentImage.attr('title') != ''){
                    var title = vars.currentImage.attr('title');
                    if(title.substr(0, 1) == '#') title = $(title).html();  

                    if(nivoCaption.css('display') == 'block'){
                        nivoCaption.find('p').fadeOut(settings.animSpeed, function(){
                            $(this).html(title);
                            $(this).fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);
                        });
                    } else {
                        nivoCaption.find('p').html(title);
                    }                   
                    nivoCaption.fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);
                } else {
                    nivoCaption.fadeOut(settings.animSpeed);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Try if(vars.currentImage.attr('title')){

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

**Soultion**

[$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) will return empty string if it is `undefined` or it has only `whitespace` .

```
if($.trim($('#abc').attr('title')) != ''){
```

**Problem**

if `vars.currentImage.attr('title')` doesn't have title attribute will return `undefined` not `''` (empty string) . And you are checking for empty string so it goes inside the loop if it doesn't have title attribute

So you get error because `substr` can only be applied to `string`.

Comment: didn't know trim function returned that

Answer (score 3):

**check the variable for null** before calling `substr()`

```
if (val1 != null) {
     var val2= val1.substr(6);
     //......
}
```