# TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring') in node js

Tags: node.js, substring

I am trying to get a part of a string.

```
let someValue = 'basic jkclwkjkvhrvhkuirhiehvyrbuyrbevnervnhrev';
let getSubstringValue = someValue.substring(6);
```

But, in my node JS server gives,

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
```

Also used 'substr' using '[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194238/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-substr-of-undefined)'. But it also gave this 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substr')' error.

Comment: At first try to check [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) of `someValue` variable. Seems like it's not a string.

Comment: yes it is a string

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you add stack snippets

Comment: change `let` to `var`

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug `someValue` if it is a string? 
If it's `undefined`, you get the error 
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`

Simple example of substring:

```
exampleVal = 'test';

// remove the first character
exampleVal = exampleVal.substring(1);

// show results (output is 'est')
console.log(exampleVal);

// example for if exampleVal is undefined

let exampleVar = undefined;
exampleVar = exampleVar.substring(1);
console.log(exampleVar);

// error is thrown 
// TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
```

Comment: I added the example of someValue to the code. Yes, it is a string

Comment: check this please https://jsfiddle.net/ztqabywm/1/